# Restrict VPN user to Remote Desktop only with Sonicwall

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vpn, port-forwarding, sonicwall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict VPN user to Remote Desktop only with Sonicwall](https://serverfault.com/questions/370045/restrict-vpn-user-to-remote-desktop-only-with-sonicwall)

Basically I want him to only be able to log onto the VPN in order to use Remote Desktop to use HIS machine. Not surf the internet or do anything like that, but just use the programs on his machine that he doesn't have at home.

We use a Sonicwall NSA 220 with their regular VPN client.

I can create a user for him, but when I create an access rule it applies to all VPN users. How can I make something like that only apply to ONE user?

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't all copy->paste like I wanted. I added a little too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sonicwall,  but if you can assign a permanent ip to the vpn user,  then you can easily restrict the network access to a single ip.